grub config bug after kernel install
I have a more than dual boot system including 3x Linux OS and 2x Windows. In the last few months I noticed that my Ubuntu 18.04 no longer boots due to grub not being configured correctly, as it misidentifies the device it is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p1 should be /dev/nvme1n1p1. As a result it is loading the kernel from the Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel argument root=/root/ instead of root=/ on the wrong device entirely (easily fixed by editing the boot config everything boots OK). Ironically every other OS boots just fine.
I always wondered if dual boot multi Linux running grub would cause conflicts, i.e. upgrading grub on the older distribution causing problems (and it happened but on the newest version.)
Does anyone have any insight into this issue?
Please see some of the update log below after installing a new kernel.
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-28-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable 
partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme1n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) on /dev/sda3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...


When using multiple OS'es with EFI, you have 2 options: 1.) 1 and only 1 EFI partition on on disk/USB/NVMe etc or 2.) Multiple EFI partitions, i.e., one for each Linux, and Windows across multiple drives if necessary.  I recommend using a Boot Manager like Refind to manage 1 and only 1 Partition.  The most likely cause of your error was a UUID change, i.e the linux installer you used found your current EFI partition, and chose a new UUID when installing it's copy of Grub. Edit the non-working /etc/fstab to match the new UUID

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

FYI:  Dual booting multiple GNU/Linux systems shouldn't create a problem; I have many systems here and almost all have 2+ GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) systems on them; up to 7 in fact...   Not all OSes carry the patches that Ubuntu does that revert 2.06 GRUB behavior being the only issue I've noticed; and that patch can be ignored in certain circumstances (so Ubuntu acts like others GNU/Linux & doesn't scan for other OSes by default) but that is rare. Main issues are file-system related (eg. BTRFS or non-native fs can cause partitions to be skipped in scan)

Also 19.04 has reached End of standard support. Best to just install LTS versions. If using multiple installs best to manage it your self. copy boot stanzas into 40_custom and use the standard links so updates in other installs do not change boot stanza, examples from cavfan
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046
Using 40_custom & Custom menu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus
